# how to use left outer join with like/or like

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm creating a search function. My sql query uses `LIKE` and `OR LIKE` in the where clause. One of the fields in the table I'm searching in is called `quantity_types` where it stores only codes that corresponds to the values found in another table. So to retrieve the values from the other, I want to use a `Left Outer Join` in my query.

Here's my sample code:

```
SELECT * FROM `pharmacy_items`
LEFT OUTER JOIN pharmacy_quantity_types
ON pharmacy_items.quantity_type = pharmacy_quantity_types.id
AND 'pharmacy_items.name' LIKE '%query_here%'
OR 'pharmacy_items.description' LIKE '%query_here%'
```

This query returns all the records in my `pharmacy_items` table instead of those records which are supposed to be returned with I'm not using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

How would I build my query such that the returned results are those that satisfies first the `WHERE` clause before the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM pharmacy_items
  LEFT
 OUTER
  JOIN pharmacy_quantity_types
    ON pharmacy_items.quantity_type = pharmacy_quantity_types.id
 WHERE pharmacy_items.name LIKE '%query_here%'
    OR pharmacy_items.description LIKE '%query_here%'
```

where the restrictions on `pharmacy_items` records are in a `WHERE` clause rather than in a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`'s `ON` clause.

(Also note:

- `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`, so `a AND b OR C` means `(a AND b) OR c`, whereas I think you wanted `a AND (b OR C)`. The above query fixes this implicitly, by moving `b OR c` into a `WHERE` clause, so it's separated from `a` anyway.
- `'...'` is a literal string, so `'pharmacy_items.name'` means "the actual string `pharmacy_items.name`", which is not the same as "the `name` field of the `pharmacy_items` record". The latter is written `pharmacy_items.name` or `` `pharmacy_items`.`name` ``.)

)

Comment: great clarification on precedence of AND/OR.

Comment: thank you. it worked :D at first i thought you can't simply add a `WHERE` when you already have `ON` because when I tested it with `phpMyAdmin`, it simply does not work. I wonder why that behavior.